# How to refer to a changing path in Ant?

Tags: ant

I have a dynamic path in my server inside which resides a file to be updated.

I am using Ant to make the file changes. But it does not seem to identify the path.

I have defined it in the following way:

`<replaceregexp file="/tmp/automation/server/main*/main*/webserver/apache-tomcat.*/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml" match="https://api.test.com" replace="${test-Endpoint}" byline="true" />`

Here 'main' is suffixed with the time-stamp and hence keep changing on every installation.

Comment: You don't have any handler to get timestamp value collected in property?, With '*' it doesn't seem to work.